# Was Ubuntu or my Network Hacked?

Tags: security

I noticed my computer was not responding properly and the time changed at the top of my window.

- Have I been hacked?
- How do I prevent it?

This is a new installation of Ubuntu. The drive is encrypted and I changed my password.

Just after I disconnected the Internet cable a lady claiming to be from Windows called. And my computer returned to normal.

I know my 3 other windows computers were hacked by a person pretending to be a Dell technician.

- rIs my network compromised? 
  The Ubuntu hack to be more specific: I found my time at the top of my window had changed and I found my mouse pointer was sluggish. It then locked up and would not move. I unplugged my internet connection and these errors cleared up. Then 3 minutes later I got the phone call. I don't know how this could be hacked since I reinstalled Ubuntu 17.04 and changed my password and encrypted my drive after the Dell hacking of which I am still recovering. Could my network which is simply connected on ethernet to my cable provider have been hacked?? –

Comment: Keep this in mind: Tech support never calls you, you call them. A callback may be arranged but only *after* you call them. Otherwise **it's a scam, always**. And if you think encryption offers some online protection, you don't understand encryption.

Comment: Wonder - What happened during the discussion with the lady? did you give her some information? Did you press a link she sent you? did you execute several commands according to her instructions?

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVQoAlQrnSg) amusing/informational.

Comment: @MichaelBay Your comments need more [explosions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7ssUivM-eM).

Comment: you can scan your system with clamav and search the log files for strange entries ...

Comment: "Not responding properly" is a bit too vague for an accurate diagnosis. Can you please edit your question to be more specific?

Comment: Be specific. "not responding properly" really does not give any useful information.

Comment: 1) The lady that called claimed to be from Windows. I simply asked her name and what it was about and she hung up. Previously I got socially engineered by a hacker claiming to be a Dell technician and he got access to my 3 Dell windows machines. He had valid service tags for all those computers so I let him into them thinking it was normal security maintenance.

Comment: 2) The Ubuntu hack to be more specific: I found my time at the top of my window had changed and I found my mouse pointer was sluggish. It then locked up and would not move. I unplugged my internet connection and these errors cleared up. Then 3 minutes later I got the phone call. I don't know how this could be hacked since I reinstalled Ubuntu 17.04 and changed my password and encrypted my drive after the Dell hacking of which I am still recovering. Could my network which is simply connected on ethernet to my cable provider have been hacked??

Comment: @2IRN clamav is not really going to help much, if at all, with Ubuntu security. It has a few user cases, but does nothing against things such as meltdown / specter and most if not all of the linux vulnerabilities (there are currently no known active linux viruses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would wipe all my computers and do fresh install to all of them. Usually a virus would not stick after a fresh install (unless it is a state level one, which is quite hard to come by).

These sounds like you have something in one of your computers in the lan that allows some one to play with your other computers.

Or you downloaded and executed something malicious and don't recall it.

Comment: Yes I have rebuilt all my computers. I am now suspecting the printer which is wireless may have something in it. However I am not sure how to wipe that away. I have not heard of a virus checker for printers. But I have seen information on the internet that printers are a hazard.